# How to shrink an object's size and repeat it around a circle?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am looking for a way to repeat an object around a circle and at the same time shrink the object for every repeat.

It's easy to repeat an object by placing it outside the circle

- select rotate tool
- hold alt and click in the center of the circle
- set the angle in the popup window
- ctrl d to repeat.

But how can I achieve the same effect while also shrinking the size of the object?

I've also tried the: effect -> Distort & Transform -> Transform tool, but didn't manage to create this effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to achieve the result below??!

[image: Image Rotation]

To achieve this, you only need the blend tool.

First start with the two objects (your starting point and your end point). Position them so they are overlapping. Select both objects and select Object > Blend > Make.

Now create an empty circle from the rotation point, with a black stroke. make sure that the top of this circle meets the center point of your objects.

With the circle selected, select the 'Scissors Tool' and click on the top point of the circle (to break it apart).

Finally, select both objects and the circle and select Object > Blend > Replace Spine. This will create the blend following the circle path – you may want to go to the Bland Options and change the spacing to 'Specified Steps' and play around with the number to achieve the desired results.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot, much appreciated. ^^

Answer (score 3):

Create object and shrinked object of the same object. Blend specified steps.
That will create a blend. Draw a Circle. Select blend object and circle. Go to object, blend and replace spine.

Comment: This works unless you want the shape to also rotate. Good for circles not so good for complex shapes, also it will be linear not exponential like a compound scale. +1 anyway

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it made it a bit more clear to understand much appreciated  :)